# Is there a way to export Photoshop Layer to Illustrator in PS Action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a Photoshop Action that:

does some things in PS,
copies/pastes layer into Illustrator,
does 1 Illustrator effect,
returns results back to PS

I'm not sure how to copy/paste to Illustrator? Is this possible in any way?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way, since every time you go back to illustrator you change a smart object, which should not affect your action, but what illustrator effect do you want to make? It might be able to be done within photoshop

Comment: Thanks Naty, after playing with it for awhile I kind of figured it wasn't possible. I was hoping there might be a way to script it, etc? Thanks anyway!